# Is there a way to not automatically show Issues Navigator when running app?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

With XCode 5, one of the issues that I frequently encounter is that there are many warnings about misplaced views when using Storyboard. While I know how to resolve these warnings, as my UI is prone to changes, I typically leave them the way it is when I am building and testing the app in early stages. Because of these unresolved warnings, XCode will **always** go to the Issue Navigators pane when I run an app to show these warnings, and this navigates away from the previous pane that I am in.

My question is, is there a way to disable the automatic navigation to the Issues Navigator when I run app?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be controlled in Preferences Behaviors Running.